# how to add composite unique to a column in the table mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table:

1. `user_id           int  Composite Unique (deal_id + user_id+deal_type)`.
2. `deal_id           int`
3. `deal_type         varchar`.
4. `created_on        datetime`.

This is my table. I want to create a composite unique on the `user_id` column so that a single user can have only unique `deal_id` for each `deal_type`.

How to make composite unique for ***in mysql phpmyadmin***.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE KEY (user_id, deal_type, deal_id);
```