# Stop user from signing up for an event two times

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I'm using `MYSQL` because the servers at my university have not updated their `servers` for `mySQLI'.

[image: Table]

Above is the table, test is going to attend all events, but I don't want test to attend the event again.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['register'])!=''){

$user = $name;
$eventTitle = $_REQUEST['select'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Event FROM attend where Event != '$eventTitle'"); // run the query and assign the result to $result
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result

        echo $table[0];
        if($table[0] == $eventTitle)
        {
            echo "dont add";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"add";
        }
}

/*$sql="INSERT INTO `assignment`.`attend` (`User`, `Event`) VALUES ('$user', '$eventTitle')";

$res=mysql_query($sql);

 if($res)
 {
    Echo "Record successfully inserted";
    //header("location: myTickets.php");
 }
 Else
 {
    Echo "There is some problem in inserting record";
     //echo $name;

 }
```

I'm tried looping through the 'Event' row to see if the value in there equals the value selected. But since it's a while loop it will keep on looping.

Pseudo code wise

```
if(the value selected is == the value in the table && and the name is == to data in the User row then do not add, else add;
```

Comment: add a unique key on user and event

Comment: apply uniqueness on the database level. then simply *try to* `INSERT`.

Comment: MySQLi was introduced in PHP 5.0. Your university is running PHP4? That's... impressive, but yes, possible.

Comment: @Dagon wouldn't the unique key disable the feature where a user can attend multiple events?

Comment: no unique on 2 fields both user and event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this in PHP. Instead, create a UNIQUE key on `user` and `event` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12880457/1544337) how to do that). So that is *one* key on *two* columns. That means that any pair of values in these two columns can only appear once. However, users can attend multiple events, and events can be attended by multiple users.

Like this you can keep your PHP much smaller.

Besides, this while loop won't keep looping: it finishes when there are no results anymore.

Another idea, more from a UX point of view, is to give users who have already subscribed to an event not the possibility to subscribe again - for example by changing the subscribe button into an unsubscribe button, or removing it completely. However, always make sure that users who're going to start tweaking requests can't still subscribe a second time - by adding the UNIQUE key, for example.

Comment: Create a unique key on user and event. Ah, I see, this does make sense and does not involve scripting much. 

Yeah, the while loop was a quick test/implementation without putting though. 

Yeah, I am adding a withdraw button, so users can stop going to the event. This is where the UNIQUE key comes in handy.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. Implementing the withdraw would be just making a query that drops those two values right?

Comment: @Moynul Happy to hear -- yes, exactly. Alternatively, might you want to include a feature that you can check which users have subscribed and withdrawn, you could add another column for that. But dropping is the simplest solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the row with the event and if you get a result. Then add.

Answer (score 0):

They won't cause your excluding the event from your search query with Event != '$eventTitle'

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on the combination user/event (this is also a perfect primary key).
On collisions you'll get a unique constraint violation